# how to open email with attachments from browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook, email-attachments

How can I open an email from a website with an attachment? I prefer to use client side code, but I can use server side as well if that's the only way. All users using my site have outlook and have permission to access the directory where the files are sitting. I'm using MVC (C#). I need it work in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you'd use a mailto link, but it does nto support attachments. You can dynamically generate an EML (MIME) file and let the user download it - Outlook will display it with all its data including attachments. Set "X-Unsent" MIME header to "1" to make sure it is shown as unsent.

Comment: Thank you, I assume I need to create that in server side code?